# IntelliJ not displaying compile time errors within IDE

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

When I attempt to build my mixed Scala/Java project I receive these errors :

[image]

Using the same project code in Eclipse does not cause these errors. Also, in the Intellij IDE there are no compilation problems for the file itself :

[image]

This case class seems fine so why the error ?

Is there an option in IntelliJ so that compile errors are displayed within the IDE instead of having to perform a build in order to find compile errors ?

Version :

[image]

Comment: What version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: @barnesjd version added to question

Comment: eclipse constantly compiles your code in the background on every change of the file, idea doesn't do this because it is wasteful and makes eclipse sluggish and piggy. you can tell it to do this but it isn't the default

Comment: Not sure about this case exactly, but did you try to enable type-aware highlightling? Look to the status bar at the bottom of IDEA window. In its right part there will be either green `[T]` icon or yellow `[_]` icon. Yellow icon means that type-aware highlighting is disabled. Click on the icon to switch these modes. Type-aware highlighting in IDEA is pretty good, there is no reason not to enable it.

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev this was turned off, nice! thanks